# Self study plan for Riemann Geometry

Tags: soft-question, manifolds, riemannian-geometry

I'm finishing my PhD in applied math (control theory but my interest is more general than just to applications in control) and I want to study Riemannian geometry, the catch is that all my "knowledge" of differential geometry is from my bachelor in physics.

I'm planning using Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifolds. In the prerequisites it says

> This subject draws on most of the topics that are covered in a typical undergraduate
> mathematics education. The appendices (which most readers should read, or at least
> skim, first) contain a cursory summary of prerequisite material on topology, linear
> algebra, calculus, and differential equations.

It is a good path? Should I add a supplementary differential geometry first?

Comment: It really depends on what your goal is. A lot of people jump directly into Riemannian geometry, There are RG textbook that has preliminary chapters on basis in differential geometry, for example [this one](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-642-18855-8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

John Lee's "Introduction to Smooth Manifolds" is the second entry in his trilogy of graduate/advanced-undergraduate level differential topology and geometry texts.

Since you almost certainly have sufficient experience with linear algebra, calculus, and differential equations, I highly recommend starting with the first text: "Introduction to Topological Manifolds". Even if you are already strong in topology, check out the table of contents and make sure you know everything in this text, as it will be assumed knowledge for "Smooth Manifolds".

Additionally, if your goal is become proficient in Riemannian geometry, the second text will not be sufficient, and you will want to follow-up with the third text: "Introduction to Riemannian Manifolds".

It's a bit of a time investment to read three texts, though. If you're impatient, you can try jumping into "Riemannian Manifolds" and see if your existing knowledge of DG can carry you. If you start hitting walls, though, you now know where to go to fill those gaps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I think I'll go through the topology book a little bit more faster to reach the second. In regard the second, my issue is that for differential geo I did not had a formal subject in it. Do you think that by going through the SM I'll need to proper study diff geo first?

Comment: This series *is* the proper differential geometry study you're looking for. It doesn't ask for any prior knowledge, understanding, or intuition on the subject, and is fully formal.